# Combining team probabilities

Tags: probability

I’m trying to establish what the combined probability would be for a certain event to occur, where there are 2 teams involved, and I know the probability of the event for EACH team. The event is 'bookings' within a football match. In addition, I'm also trying to establish what impact on the probability a third party would have (the referee), as they are a contributing factor to the event of a player being booked (shown a card).

The following is what I'm looking to establish:

1. The probability of 4+ bookings the match
2. The probability of 2+ bookings to Team A in the match
3. The probability of 2+ bookings to Team B in the match
4. The probability of 2+ bookings to Team A & 2+ bookings to Team B in the match

The following is the data that relates to the recent 5 matches played both Team A & Team B (not against each other), plus the most recent 5 matches the referee has refereed.

Team A received cards in previous 5 matches:

- Match 1 (2 bookings)
- Match 2 (1 booking)
- Match 3 (2 bookings)
- Match 4 (3 bookings)
- Match 5 (2 bookings)

So, 2 or more cards shown to Team A occurs 80% of the time (0.8)

Team B received cards in previous 5 matches:

- Match 1 (1 booking)
- Match 2 (4 bookings)
- Match 3 (2 bookings)
- Match 4 (2 bookings)
- Match 5 (0 bookings)

So, 2 or more cards shown to Team A occurs 60% of the time (0.6)

Referee cards shown in previous 5 matches (assume no team bias):

- Match 1 (1 booking)
- Match 2 (4 bookings)
- Match 3 (5 bookings)
- Match 4 (4 bookings)
- Match 5 (6 bookings)

So, 4 or more cards are shown to either team 80% of the time (0.8)

Hopefully the above makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards G

Comment: Perhaps you could model the number of bookings as a Poisson process? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution
Then, the problem becomes estimating the parameter $\lambda$ from the data.

Comment: Also, it's not very clear what you want exactly. Is it so that you assume that you know the probability distribution for the number of bookings for each team? For example, let the number of bookings be $X$. Then you have said
$$
P(X\geq 2 | A) = 0.8 \qquad
P(X\geq 2 | B) = 0.6 \qquad 
P(X\geq 2 | C) = 0.8
$$
And now, do I interpret that what you want to calculate (in the first of the four questions) after this is just the probability
$$
P(X \geq 4)
$$
without the conditioning. Do I interpret this correctly?

Comment: Yes, you did interpret that correctly/ Apologies, I should have been clearer. 4+ indicates 4 OR MORE, and 2+ in my questions indicates 2 OR MORE.